# edit_entries_additional_celldata

Tags: ee2, control-panel, add-on-development

I'm looking for a way to display entries in the control panel in the order of being last updated. I saw that EE1 has the hook edit_entries_additional_celldata but it's not present in EE2. Is there any other way I can add new columns to the search entries table in the CP?

Comment: Since you're asking about add-on dev, I'll post here, but take a look at Zenbu. Well worth the money for improved control panel entry viewing. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu

Comment: Thanks, that addon is exactly what I'm thinking of, I wonder how they do it.